# How to use Flutter go_router for routes with object parameters

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I want to migrate to app_link and universal links for deep linking from Firebase dynamic links.

now I try very hard to understand how the go_router package works, it's kinda like it's working based on url structure whereas in my app I'm still using object parameters between pages or screens when navigating.

And if I do migrate to go_router completely I have to change the entire app!, changing every parameter to strings (since go_router only supports strings, and an extra parameter to pass objects which is not fulfilling my needs). or decoding and encoding each object parameters before navigating. in both cases it's a lot of work and I don't like these approaches.

I was wondering if it's ok to use go_router just for dynamic links? and use Flutter navigator for normal navigations between the pages (which I think it's kinda strange to overload the app just using it for one thing and not using it for routing throughout the app).

Or there's a better way or I didn't understand it quietly.

Please I need some explanations. And how did you guys integrate it? Especially for navigations with object parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the documentation of the `go_router` answers your question exactly:

> GoRouter leverages the Router API to provide backward compatibility
> with the Navigator, so any calls to Navigator.of(context).push() or
> Navigator.of(context).pop() will continue to work, but these
> destinations aren't deep-linkable. **You can gradually add more routes**
> **to the GoRouter configuration**.

https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Upgrading-topic.html

ie. Yes, you can start by just using GoRouter for your deep-linking needs and use Navigator API for everything else.